# Problema com Nuget Packages Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tentando compilar a aplicação, me deparo com o erro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.    ControlePatrimonial E:\Projetos
>   Visual Studio\Projetos
>   VisualStudio2015\ControlePatrimonial\ControlePatrimonial.csproj   356

Já tentei o seguinte:

- Update-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -reinstall
- Remover a linha no `packages.config`
- Tirar a a pasta da Package, e colocar outra de outro projeto.
- Excluir a pasta e instalar de novo via nuget

Porém, nenhuma dessas tentativas obteve sucesso. 
Como resolvo este problema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você possivelmente moveu alguma coisa de lugar e perdeu a referência entre diretórios.

Abra o arquivo .csproj da sua solução como texto (no VS ou no Bloco de Notas) e verifique o diretório onde está a referência de `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2`. Salve o arquivo e reabra a solução.

Comment: Valeu, me mostrou o caminho do que precisava ser feito.